# Let $ w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $W$. If $v = a_1\cdot w_1+a_2\cdot w_2+\dots+a_n\cdot w_n$, then $a_1 = ?\ a_2=?\ a_n = ?$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, change-of-basis

Let $w_1, w_2,\dots, w_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $W$. 
If $v = a_1\cdot w_1+a_2\cdot w_2+\dots+a_n\cdot w_n$, 
then $a_1 = ?\ a_2=?\ a_n = ?$

How do I find the scalars $a_1, a_2$, and $a_n$ ?

Comment: Please write your problem using MathJax : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $a_i= \langle v, w_i \rangle$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is the v and wi in the opposite order?

Answer (score 0):

Since $W^{-1} = W^T$: $Wa=v \iff W^TWa=W^Tv \iff a=W^Tv$

Comment: would it be ai = <wi , v> ?

Comment: Yes, $a_i= \langle v, w_i \rangle = \langle w_i, v \rangle = w_i^Tv$. :-)